# How to delete all products in a specific category on magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, category-products

How to delete all products from a specific category in Magento 2? or delete products by category id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is, according to Magento best practices.

```
<?php 

class CategoryDeleter
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * CategoryDeleter constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface  $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return array
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException
     */
    public function deleteProductsByCategoryId($id)
    {
        $deletedIds = [];

        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface|\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category */
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($id);
        $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
            $this->productRepository->delete($product);
            $deletedIds[] = $product->getId();
        }

        return $deletedIds;
    }
}
```

---

If this is just a one-time script and you don't want to create a full module for it, you could run the script below from the root of your Magento installation. Just make sure to replace my sample category id (7) with your actual category ID.

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$registry = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Registry::class);
$registry->register('isSecureArea', true);

class CategoryDeleter
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * CategoryDeleter constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface  $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return array
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException
     */
    public function deleteProductsByCategoryId($id)
    {
        $deletedIds = [];

        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface|\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category */
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($id);
        $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
            $this->productRepository->delete($product);
            $deletedIds[] = $product->getId();
        }

        return $deletedIds;
    }
}

/** @var \CategoryDeleter $class */
$class = $objectManager->create(\CategoryDeleter::class);
$class->deleteProductsByCategoryId(7);
```

Comment: I don't think you should load a category and call `getProductCollection()`. The repository will return an instance that complies with `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface` and this does not have a `getProductCollection()`. While this code may work for now, it's no guarantee that it will work in future Magento releases. Always rely on abstraction, not concretion. So if a method is not available in the interface, it's best practice to find another solution (like the `CategoryLinkManagementInterface`), even though it works "for now". Chances are that it's not forward-compatible.

Comment: @GielBerkers I am pretty sure this is a one-time script. I DID NOT deserve the down vote. My answer is the best of the 3.

Comment: I did not give you a downvote. Somebody else did. Your answer is correct, but I am just pointing out some improvements.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It musta been the guy who I downvoted for suggesting this be done with an SQL query.

Comment: Here, have my upvote ;-)

Comment: Right back at you :-)

Comment: @ShawnAbramson Thank you. This is the only code that works for me. and BTW it only deletes visible products.

Comment: That script works great. But it would be much more useful if it could remove all products from category, only remove from that particular category, not delete the products altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way is to use Magento's Service Contracts for this. Especially `Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface::getAssignedProducts()` looks right for the job, because that's a management class that can be used to get category/product-links (which is exactly what you want):

```
namespace Vendor\Module;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

/**
 * Class CategoryDeleter
 * @package Vendor\Module
 */
class CategoryDeleter
{
    /**
     * @var CategoryLinkManagementInterface
     */
    protected $categoryLinkManagement;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * CategoryDeleter constructor.
     * @param CategoryLinkManagementInterface $categoryLinkManagement
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        CategoryLinkManagementInterface $categoryLinkManagement,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->categoryLinkManagement = $categoryLinkManagement;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $categoryId
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException
     */
    public function deleteProductsByCategoryId(int $categoryId)
    {
        foreach ($this->categoryLinkManagement->getAssignedProducts($categoryId) as $categoryProductLink) {
            $this->productRepository->deleteById($categoryProductLink->getSku());
        }
    }
}
```